# Why does Java8 Stream.min() and max() takes comparator as input?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Isn't it obvious that min() function should compute the minimum element in the collection and return us the data?

I can accept the fact for User defined objects like Person, Animal etc... we have to provide comparator to compute the min element. But for universally accepted types like Integer, String, Double why does it try to accept comparator implementation.

It could have been overloaded functions like?

1.

```
min() => Just for types like Integer, String, Double etc..
```

2.

```
min(Comparator c) => for types like user defined objects like Person etc...
```

eg.,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

The fact that list.stream().min(/*I can still pass a comparator that computes maximum Integer data and breach the underlying intent of the function right?*/)

Comment: ... and for the types like `int`, `double` and `long` you can use `IntStream.min`, `DoubleStream.min` and `LongStream.min`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way `min()` could work without a `Comparator` was if the element type `T` of the `Stream<T>` was bound to implement `Comparable<T>`.

However, the `Stream` interface should support both element types that implement `Comparable` and element types that don't. Therefore, you must pass a `Comparator<T>` to `min()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to provide a method only when it is a stream of `Comparable` instances. All instances of stream have to have the same methods.

Comment: I can accept that? BUT,

The fact that list.stream().min(/I can still pass a comparator that computes maximum Integer data and breach the underlying intent of the function right?/)

Comment: Yes. It's just the same as `Collections.max` and `Collections.min` in that respect.

Comment: And I would argue that the does NOT breach the intent.  The `min` method is returning the smallest value *according to the ordering that you specified with the `Comparator`*.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because the general `Stream` class cannot extinguise between primitive types and their Object counterparts (what to do with an empty/null ellement list?). The `IntStream` (and other primitive stream types) does have that functionality. E.g.

```
List<Integer> list;
list.stream().mapToInt(I -> I).min(); // max();
```

Hope this gives you a perspecitve on this.